# Image acts differently on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have two responsive images that shrink in size as the browser window shrinks.
The images work fine on Chrome and Edge but for Firefox one of the image acts different, it stops shrinking. 
Can anyone help me out with this? You can see the issue in mobile view.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

This is my code:

```css
.row-images {
  display: flex;
}

.main-image {
  float: left;
}

img {
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.side-image {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-left: 4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-images">
  <div class="main-image"><img src="http://icabinets.joomji.com/skin/frontend/ultimo/child/images/row10.png"></div>
  <div class="side-image"><img src="http://icabinets.joomji.com/skin/frontend/ultimo/child/images/row10_side.png"></div>
</div>
```

I have my code **[here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpXVMR)**

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code**

```css
.row-images {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.side-image{
  margin-left:4%;
}
img {max-width:100%;}
```

```html
  <div class="row-images"> 
    <div class="main-image">
      <img src="http://icabinets.joomji.com/skin/frontend/ultimo/child/images/row10.png">
    </div>
    <div class="side-image">
     <img src="http://icabinets.joomji.com/skin/frontend/ultimo/child/images/row10_side.png">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems like the same issue is happening for Firefox though.

Comment: can you share the firefox version

Comment: with your code, the right image is larger than the let image in Firefox. I would like it to look like the image I attached in my post under chrome and edge.

Comment: i think its due to browser version.It look fine on mine firefox (version 52).could you upgrade to the latest version of Firefox and see if the issue is still present?

Comment: hmm not sure what the issue is then because i'm using 52.0.2